# JS YouTube API Chromeless Player

Tags: javascript, html, flash, youtube-api

How would i embed a chromeless YouTube Player into my webpage, The YouTube api Documents only give Javascript functions, do you embed with iframe or use a video tag and also how do you control the chromeless player.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd call the javascript function as per the documentation,

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

but add arguments to it.  Basically, you create a div on your page with a particular ID

```
<div id=myplayer></div>
```

then call the youtube player javascript

```
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('myplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
      }
    });
  }
```

but with specific arguments from the list here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

so we'd add those playerVars into the function, replacing the function above with this:

```
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('myplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      playerVars: { 'controls': 0, 'showinfo': 0 }
    });
  }
```

Then, you'd use javascript to stop/pause/start the video

```
player.playVideo()
player.pauseVideo()
player.stopVideo()
```

The most basic approach would be to make these onclick events for links, eg

```
<a href='#' onclick='javascript:player.playVideo(); return true;'>Play</a>
```

etc.

Comment: thanks, and by the way, who put this down, its a valid programming question