# Youtube iframe API: Differentiate "playing because click" versus "playing because playVideo()"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

A youtube player has this handler for the `onStateChange` event:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        if (event.something) {
            console.log("The player is playing because the user clicked the 'play' button")
        } else {
            console.log("The player is playing because player.playVideo() was called programatically");
        }
    }
}
```

Question:
Is there a property, `something`, in the object `event` that I could use for determining the source of the `playing state` ?

I need to differentiate the `playing state` in its two possible causes:

- Playing because the user clicked the "play" button
- Playing because the code programatically called `player.playVideo()`

Is this possible with the API? if not, any ideas on how to achieve it in an elegant manner?

Comment: Maybe if this is not possible through the event properties, I could wrap the entire player in an invisible DIV and use a `clickedOnDiv` flag? `if (clickedOnDiv) { clickedOnDiv = false; etc.. }`

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube Iframe Player API does not expose any events from the player controls themselves, and I don't think that wrapping things in a DIV will help, as click events don't bubble up past an iFrame. You could embed a chromeless player and then construct your own player controls bar; that way, you'd have full access to your control buttons and could capture click events on them.

Comment: That's a boomer. What if the DIV is in top of the iframe (z-index)? So that every click in the player is also a click in the div

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "embed a chromeless player"? is it possible with youtube videos? Having my own controls (play, pause and the timeline drag)  would be the best

Comment: The problem is if you put a div on top of the iframe and it captures the clicks, then the buttons underneath would never receive those clicks. The chromeless player is the best way to go; you load a YouTube video without any of its controls, create your own in HTML, and bind your buttons to different methods of the player's javascript API. Here's an SO question that has a great answer which can get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745862/js-youtube-api-chromeless-player